# How to connect my Kibana to ElasticSearch in the docker run command?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana

Just trying to learn to setup Kibana and Elastic search using native docker command (i.e. not using Docker-Compose).

Below are the commands I run

```
docker network create es-net

docker run -d --name es-cluster \
--net es-net -p 9200:9200 \
-e "xpack.security.enabled=false" \
-e "discovery.type=single-node" \
docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.2.0

docker run -d --net es-net -p 5601:5601 \
-e ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://es-cluster:9200 \
docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.2.0
```

Somehow Kibana is not loading the elastic search up when I run `http://localhost:5601/` and always with the message `Kibana server is not ready yet`

I follow the answer as per [Kibana on Docker cannot connect to Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40341346/3286489), to ensure the `ELASTICSEARCH_URL` is correctly set, but it is still not coming up. Anything I miss?

**note: tested with `curl 0.0.0.0:9200`, the elastic search is already running**

Comment: Can you try http://host.docker.internal:5601 ?

Comment: Tried http://host.docker.internal:5601/, nothing came out :(

Answer (score 0):

Looks like since I'm in version 7.2.0 of Kibana, it has changed from `ELASTICSEARCH_URL` to `ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS`

as per https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/docker.html

```
docker run -d --net es-net -p 5601:5601 \
-e ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://es-cluster:9200 \
docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.2.0
```

With this in place, all should work then.